I wrote this code to drive car in GTA 5.However the keyboard is only simulating the keystrokes in Pycharm and not other app
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
model_path = r'C:\Users\Saransh\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\gesture_recognizer.task'                                         
BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions                                                                                      
GestureRecognizer = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizer
GestureRecognizerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerOptions
GestureRecognizerResult = mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode
def print_result(result: GestureRecognizerResult,output_image: mp.Image,timestamp_ms: int):
    if(type(result.gestures)==list and result.gestures):
        if(result.gestures[0][0].category_name=='Pointing_Up'):
            press('w')
        if(result.gestures[0][0].category_name=='Victory'):
            press('d')
        if(result.gestures[0][0].category_name=='ILoveYou'):
            press('a')
        if(result.gestures[0][0].category_name=='Closed_Fist'):
            press('s')
    if(type(result.gestures)==list and result.gestures):
        print(result.gestures[0][0].category_name)
options = GestureRecognizerOptions(                                                                                     
    base_options=     BaseOptions(model_asset_path="C:\\Users\\Saransh\\PycharmProjects\\OpenCV\\gesture_recognizer.task"),
    running_mode =VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,                
    result_callback=print_result)                               
cap= cv.VideoCapture(0)
frame_timestamp_ms = 0
with GestureRecognizer.create_from_options(options) as recognizer:
        while cap.read():
            res,frame=cap.read()
            if(res==False):
                break
            frame=cv.flip(frame,1)
            frame=cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            k=cv.waitKey(1)
            mp_image=mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB,data=frame)
            recognizer.recognize_async(mp_image,frame_timestamp_ms)
            frame_timestamp_ms+=1
        cap.release()
        cap.destroyAllWindows()

I was expecting the keystrokes to be replicated in other apps too but it is only being replicated in pycharm evironment.Can anyone help me out?It's only replicating in Pycharm and some other apps like Brave browser,spotif,notepad but not others

Using pyautogui.press() is an extremely bad idea (I've found pyautogui to be unreliable, tons of questions on stackoverflow about why pyauotgui isn't working), you should use pynput or keyboard instead. Here's an example of using keyboard: keyboard.press_and_release('w').

Tried the keyboard library too but same problem arises....Please help in any way possible

In this case, it's best to use one of the pywin32 modules, to help you out a little bit, because it seems that just emulating key presses is not enough, you need to send it directly to the application:
import win32com.client, time
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run('name of the app you are trying to run')
time.sleep(3)
shell.AppActivate('same name as earlier')
shell.SendKeys('s') #sends key s to the application

Thanks to this stackoverflow post for most of the code :)
In any case, pyautogui, keyboard, and pynput sometimes aren't able to reach an app, especially if the app is inactive (which I assume in your case it was active).
